# Триггер в Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$sql1="CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
`content` TEXT NOT NULL
) ;";
$sql2="CREATE TABLE `log` (
`id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`msg` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
`time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`row_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ;";

$sql3="CREATE TRIGGER `update_test` AFTER INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO log Set msg = 'insert', row_id = NEW.id;
END;";
//mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
//mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
$sql4="INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (4),(2),(1)";
mysql_query($sql4) or die(mysql_error());
```

Создается 2 таблицы. Через триггер при добавлении записи в одну таблицу  идет запись в другую.

**Ошибка:**

> `Thread stack overrun: 7672 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.`

И еще. Подскажите, как запретить удалять больше 5 записей в час в таблице через триггер?

Answer (score 1):

Обрати внимание на поля `test.id` и `log.row_id`. У первого `UNSIGNED`, у второго - нет. Технически, это разные типы данных.

Answer (score 0):

В файле my.cnf в месте thread_stack прописать 256k(по умолчанию 128 стоит.)
Помогло.